# Open File Limits

Tags: centos, centos7, mongodb

During the installation of mongo db I encountered a warning which says

> soft rlimits too low. rlimits set to 1024 processes, 64000 files.
>   Number of processes should be at least 32000 : 0.5 times number of
>   files.

I found quite a lot sites describing how to raise the system and user's open files limit, but I haven't found to what extent I can/should increase these values.

1. Are these values dependent on server resources? If so how can I figure out what max value I should set for my system?
2. Apparently two settings are important for mongodb's performance (the open files limit and the number of processes). How do I correctly tweak the number of processes as well? How do I check if I am using too high values?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's telling you the number of processes is too low in an absolute sense. It's telling you the *ratio* of MaxProcesses:MaxOpenFiles should be adjusted.

You'll need to decide based on your hardware, expected load, and other demands for resources what limits you want to put on the database and your other applications.

You can use `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max` to find out the max-files your entire server can have open simultaneously. Linux doesn't have an inherent limit on the number of processes, but if that number's too large relative to the number of cores, performance may suffer. You can find out what the current max-allowed threads for your server is (if any) using `cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max`. You can also write a higher or lower value to this file to tune performance. Now you know your server's overall constraints.

Next, estimate the typical and max number of simultaneous connections you expect for the db. Typically you'll want to set your per-user file limit large enough to handle at least a typical load easily. Most likely, you can choose a value that's larger than your max expected connections, but only you can decide if that makes sense for your overall use and server constraints. You can choose a value for max-processes per user that's equal to max-files, or less than max-files, but mongo is warning you to avoid setting max-processes per user to be less than half of max-files per user, presumably because each connection needs a process (thread) as well as a file.

Basically you just want to make sure you're not overly generous, risking resource exhaustion, and not overly parsimonious, risking application bottlenecks. Typically, you start with an initial guesstimate for these constraints and plan to tweak them later, if you need to, based on actual use and performance.

Once you have a guesstimate on these two resource constraints, use ulimit to set max-files and max-processes *per user*. Later, you can tweak these values based on actual use and performance.